# Setting up rulebased labelling programmatically in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

In my plugin I do some labelling a vector layer with `QgsPalLayerSettings`. This works fine for me with `QgsMapRenderer::setLabelingEngine`.

But now I also want to implement the rulebased labelling. In [API](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsRuleBasedLabeling_1_1Rule.html) I found the class `QgsRuleBasedLabeling::Rule` which I thought works similar to setting up a `QgsRuleBasedRendererV2::RuleList`.

But I can't find the point where the `QgsRuleBasedLabeling::Rule` has to be set. Ther is no member in `QgsMapRenderer`. Does anybody has a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the QGIS source code found in **qgsrulebasedlabelingwidget.cpp** the solution:

```
// also clear old-style labeling config
mLayer->removeCustomProperty( "labeling" );

mLayer->setLabeling( new QgsRuleBasedLabeling( mRootRule->clone() ) );
```

Before i adapted this code I set up my rootRule like this:

```
rootRule = new QgsRuleBasedLabeling::Rule( nullptr );
```

and added the rules in that way:

```
rootRule->appendChild(new QgsRuleBasedLabeling::Rule(set,minScale,maxScale,sWhere, nam));
```

Before I filled the 
`QgsPalLayerSettings* set= &palLyr;`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet - the relevant methods and classes aren't exposed to the python API. This will be addressed when 3.0 is released.

Comment: Oh... But my plugin is in c++, so there should be a possibility.